# One-to-one mapping confusion

Tags: sql, database

Why is it that a lot of people are referring to One-to-One when I am sure they are referring to Many-to-one?

For instance, if you have two tables;

```
Inventory (InventoryID)    
Item (ItemID, InventoryFK)
```

There is no one-to-one mapping here as far as I can tell. It's "Many items to one inventory".

Now, let's assume that there would be only **one** item per inventory. In this case, my colleagues would start calling it a "one-to-one". Am I correct in pointing out that it's **still** a many-to-one relationship? When I try to explain this to them they don't seem to understand.

I believe a proper one-to-one mapping to be something like this:

```
Person (Column: PersonID, Name)
PersonAddress (Column: PersonID, StreetName, StreetNumber)
```

Here you'd have two tables, sharing the exact same PK.

Assuming my assumptions are correct, why are so many people abusing the term "one-to-one"?

Comment: I wasn't aware people are abusing that term. And by the way, Person to Address may also be a One to Many relationship. In rare cases people may have multiple addresses.

Comment: Actually person to address may even be many to one as well, or even many to many, as any student who shared digs with twelve other disgusting slobs could attest :-)

Comment: if you add a unique constraint in `InventoryFK` you'd have a one-to-one relationship... Just because there's a foreign key, it doesn't automatically means that you have a one-to-many relationship. To me, you're mixing the "data model" (how your elements are related to each other) with the "database model" (the implementation for the database)

Comment: @pleasedontbelong: if you add a unique constraint as you describe you'd have a one-to-zero-or-one relationship.

Comment: @onedaywhen well, in that case the second example is also a one-to-zero-or-one =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one-to-many and one-to-one relation are implemented in a slightly different way.

One-to-many

Object (objectId) ObjectCharacteristics(charId,objectId)

One-to-one

The order of the table is not important:

Husband (husbandId) Wife(wifeId,husbandId) + unique constraint on husbandId

N.B. One-to-many relation is also a one-to-one relation in the order way. The ObjectCharacteristics has one and only one object.

But you are right the relationship is a concept that does not depend upon the specific data in your database but only on the structure of it.

Comment: Each ObjectCharacteristics has exactly one Object, each Object has *at most* one ObjectCharacteristics, therefore the relationship is not one-to-one but rather one-to-zero-or-one.

Comment: "The order of the table is not important" is a misstatement: see above comment showing why direction is important.

Answer (score 1):

I agree these terms are much abused. But who of us isn't guilty? Without knowing the constraints involved, your example of what you believe to be a one-to-one relationship could be a one-to-zero-or-one relationship (hint: the presence of a foreign key does not imply the presence of actual referencing values).

Chris Date wrote a very thorough analysis of the situation in his paper [All for One, One for All](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/AllforOne.pdf).